# Cumulative query with 'group by' causing slowness

Tags: sql, performance, group-by, mariadb

We have a table which will store the information of Users like deals performed, date etc. Same user can perform same deals multiple times. Now we want to display the cumulative sum of amount user performed totally if deal no is same

Query with GROUP BY Causing Slowness
Query to display cumulative sum joining the same table.
Table has 2.7 million records.
And this goes for proper index scan (Index structure).

```
INDEX `IDX_GRPBY2` (`DEAL`, `FIN`),
INDEX `Table1_TEMP` (`CREATE1`, `FEVSTATUS`, `EVE`)
```

Below is the expected result

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KtnY.png)

Below is the actual query which is used to get deals with cumulative sum if it's same deal:

```
SELECT  MAX(A.PKEY) PKEY,
        A.ENT, A.DEAL, A.FIN, A.DATE1, A.TYPE1, A.STEPNO, 
        A.CREATE1, A.EVE, A.FEVSTATUS, A.STATUSDATE, A.INTAMT,
        A.INTPAID, A.INT_TYPE, A.PENALTY_1, A.CONV_PAID_4,
        A.INT_PAID_4, A.CONVFIN_4, A.INTTYPE,
        B.DEAL AS DEAL_B, B.FIN AS FIN_B,
        SUM(B.CONV_PAID_4) AS CONV_PAID_4_OUT
    FROM  Table1 A, Table1 B
    WHERE  A.CREATE1 = '0'
      AND  (A.FEVSTATUS = '1'
              OR  A.EVE IN ('E06', 'E07', 'E02', 'E15', 'E03', 'E04')
           )
      AND  A.DEAL = B.DEAL
      AND  A.FIN = B.FIN
      AND  A.PKEY >= B.PKEY
    GROUP BY  A.ENT, A.DEAL, A.FIN, A.DATE1, A.TYPE1, A.STEPNO,
        A.CREATE1, A.EVE, A.FEVSTATUS, A.STATUSDATE, A.INTAMT,
        A.INTPAID, A.INT_TYPE, A.PENALTY_1, A.CONV_PAID_4,
        A.INT_PAID_4, A.CONVFIN_4, A.INTTYPE,
        B.DEAL, B.FIN;
```

I tried to change to below to sum up in sub query and then join, but still the result is taking very long

Changed Query:

```
SELECT  MAX(A.PKEY) PKEY, A.ENT, A.DEAL, A.FIN, A.DATE1, A.TYPE1,
        A.STEPNO, A.CREATE1, A.EVE, A.FEVSTATUS, A.STATUSDATE,
        A.INTAMT, A.INTPAID, A.INT_TYPE, A.PENALTY_1, A.CONV_PAID_4,
        A.INT_PAID_4, A.CONVFIN_4, A.INTTYPE, A.DEAL AS DEAL_B,
        A.FIN AS FIN_B, 
    (
        SELECT  SUM(B.CONV_PAID_4)
            FROM  Table1 B
            WHERE  A.DEAL = B.DEAL
              AND  A.FIN = B.FIN
              AND  A.PKEY >= B.PKEY
    ) AS PRI_CONV_PAID_4_OUT
    FROM  Table1 A
    WHERE  A.CREATE1 = '0'
      AND  (A.FEVSTATUS = '1'
              OR  A.EVE IN ('E06', 'E07', 'E02', 'E15', 'E03', 'E04')
           )
    GROUP BY  A.ENT, A.DEAL, A.FIN, A.DATE1, A.TYPE1, A.STEPNO,
        A.CREATE1, A.EVE, A.FEVSTATUS, A.STATUSDATE, A.INTAMT,
        A.INTPAID, A.INT_TYPE, A.PENALTY_1, A.CONV_PAID_4, A.INT_PAID_4,
        A.CONVFIN_4, A.INTTYPE, B.DEAL, B.FIN;
```

Any help in re-framing the query faster?

Below the show create table

```
CREATE TABLE `Table1` (
    `PKEY` DECIMAL(10,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ENT` CHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `DEAL` CHAR(14) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `FIN` CHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `DATE1` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `TYPE1` CHAR(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `STEPNO` CHAR(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CREATE1` CHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `EVE` CHAR(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `FEVSTATUS` CHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `STATUSDATE` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `INTAMT` DECIMAL(19,5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `INTPAID` DECIMAL(19,5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `INT_TYPE` CHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `PENALTY_1` DECIMAL(9,6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CONV_PAID_4` DECIMAL(15,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CONV_PAID_4` DECIMAL(19,5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CONV_FIN_4` CHAR(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `INTTYPE` CHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`PKEY`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `IXQDWFEV_PK` (`PKEY`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `IXIDWFEV` (`ENT`, `DEAL`, `FIN`, `DATE1`),
    INDEX `IXQDWFEV_GI1` (`ENT`, `DEAL`, `CONV_FIN_4`),
    INDEX `IXQDWFEV_GI2` (`ENT`, `DEAL`, `TYPE1`, `STEPNO`),
    INDEX `IDX_GRPBY2` (`DEAL`, `FIN`),
    INDEX `IXQDWFEV1_TEMP` (`CREATE1`, `FEVSTATUS`, `EVE`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
;
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried to format your code. Please double check, especially the expected output. [Edit] your question as needed.

Comment: Is it a "groupwise max" problem?  Can you simplify it?  There seem to be a lot of columns that are not relevant to the performance issue.  Also, need `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: the other columns which are not useful in this query are referred in where clause of other JOIN. This is only one part of the query

Comment: @Robert, attached the formatted expected  output.

Comment: @RickJames, groupwise sum is having problem.

Comment: Is the table `InnoDB` (not MyISAM)?  (It makes a difference in the indexes.)

Comment: @RickJames , it’s INNODB. Version: 10.2.14

Comment: @Jos8483 - Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for both formulations.  And, if available, `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`